# Ошибка при создании сокета в андроиде

Tags: java, android, сервер, client

Написал простой клиент на Android, и сервер на C#. Cервер работает как часы, а вот с клиентом проблемы. Ошибка вылетает в момент соединения. Не могу понять, что не так?
 `client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444);`

Полный код выглядит так:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Socket client;
private PrintWriter printwriter;
private EditText textField;
private Button button;
private String messsage;
String ip="127.0.0.1";
int port=4444;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textout);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            messsage = textField.getText().toString();
            Socket client =null;
            textField.setText("");
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream= null;
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

            try {

                client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444);
                client.setSoTimeout(100);
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                dataOutputStream.writeUTF(messsage);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Got an IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Зарание благодарю.

Comment: Права на использование интернета в манифест добавили?

Comment: Приведите стектрейс

Comment: да права в манифесте есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

127.0.0.1 - это localhost эмулятора на котором вы отлаживаетесь, для соединения с основной машиной нужно использовать 10.0.2.2
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses
PS
Подсмотрено на большом stackoverflow

Comment: Благодарю, помогло. Правда на эмуляторе Genymotion не удалось соединиться. А со стандартным AVD все заработало.

Comment: Ну так прочтите по нему документацию

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь лезть в сеть с основного потока.

> NetworkOnMainThreadExeption

Так нельзя (в новых версиях андроида). Пользуйтесь AsyncTask, например, чтобы работать с сетью в отдельном потоке.

Answer (score -1):

Код упростил для наглядности. Теперь ошибка не вылетает, но и соединения нет.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",4444);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        th.start();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Стектрейс, как картинка - плохая идея. Картинку с хостинга потрут и вопрос ваш не понятен будет.